# Explaining a part of proof for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n))=\mathbb{E}(f(X))$ for all $f \in C^{0}_{b}.$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

Convergence of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in distribution to $X$, implies that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n))=\mathbb{E}(f(X))$$ for all $f \in C^{0}_{b}.$

Proof: Exists a $a > 0$ with $\left | f(x) \right | \leq a$ for all $x$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We choose $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F_X$ in $t$ and $-t$ continuous is and $F_X < \dfrac{\epsilon}{16a}$ and $1 - F_X < \dfrac{\epsilon}{16a}$. Then it is $n_0(\epsilon)$ such that  $F_{X_n} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{16a}$ and $1 - F_{X_n} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{16a}$ for all $n \geq n_0(\epsilon)$. The function is in compact interval $[-t,t]$, so one can divide interval in points $t_0=-t<t_1<t_2<...<t_k=t$ are continuity points of $F_X$ and in other hand:

$$\max_{t_i \leq x  \leq t_{i+1}} f(x) - \min_{t_i \leq x  \leq t_{i+1}} f(x) \leq \frac{e}{8}$$ for $ i=0,...,k-1$.

Then is,

> $\left | \mathbb{E}(f(X)) - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}f(t_i)\mathbb{P}(t_i
>  <X<t_{i+1}) \right | \leq \mathbb{E}(\left |f(X)  \right
>  |\mathbb{1}_\left \{ \left | X \right | \geq t \right \}) +
>  \dfrac{\epsilon}{8}\mathbb{P}(\left | X \right | \leq t) \leq a \dfrac{\epsilon}{8a} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{8}=\dfrac{\epsilon}{4}$.

*Proof continues...*

**My question is:** In second step where $\mathbb{E}(\left |f(X)  \right
|\mathbb{1}_\left \{ \left | X \right | \geq t \right \})$ of highlighted text, why it is larger or equal to $\mathbb{E}(f(X))$?

Comment: Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @BCLC My doubt is for indicator function, for {$|X| \geq t$}? Since it is strange I think it should have been vice-versa!

Comment: Right, but I think Jensen's might play a role. idk

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is not a direct comparison between $\mathbb{E}(\left |f(X)  \right
|\mathbb{1}_\left \{ \left | X \right | \geq t \right \})$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(\left|f(X)\right| \right)$. What is used is the following:
\begin{align}
\left | \mathbb{E}(f(X)) - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}f(t_i)\mathbb{P}(t_i
 <X<t_{i+1}) \right |&=\left | \mathbb{E}(f(X)\mathbb 1\{|X|\geqslant t\}) +\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mathbb 1\{|X|\lt t\})- \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}f(t_i)\mathbb{P}(t_i
 <X<t_{i+1}) \right |\\
&\leqslant \left|\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mathbb 1\{|X|\geqslant t\}\right|+
\left|\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mathbb E\left[\left(f(X)-f(t_i)\right)\mathbb 1\left\{t_i\leqslant X\lt t_{i+1}\right\}\right]\right|\\
&\leqslant  \mathbb{E}\left[\left|f(X)\right|\mathbb 1\{|X|\geqslant t\}\right]+
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mathbb E\left[\left|f(X)-f(t_i)\right|\mathbb 1\left\{t_i\leqslant X\lt t_{i+1}\right\}\right],
\end{align}
from which the wanted inequality follows.

Comment: @DavidGiraudo I want to ask also another question ... Why in this case we bound absolute value of f(x) with a constant that is "a"... and in dominated convergence with a function which is g(x)?

Comment: In this context, the dominating can be chosen to be constant.